# No Wireless Adapter showing

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, network-adapter

All of a sudden I cannot connect to Wireless networks with my laptop. There is no wireless adapter shown in device manager or Network and Sharing Center. In "Manage Wireless Networks" it says that wireless is not currently enabled. I have Lenovo B580 with Windows 7.

Things I have already tried and did not work:

-System restore to date when everything worked fine

-I checked in Bios that WLAN radio is ON.

-I reinstalled Realtek driver.

When I turn on my computer there is the icon in the toolbar that it is trying to connect to a wireless network.

Any other suggestions? Could it be some hardware failure? I am actually unsure what the right driver is to install, I chose Realtek because the cable connection has the same name.

Comment: Please check for a physical HW switch or keyboard combination (FN+F2 for Dell Vostro) that controls power to WLAN card. On closer inspection if WLAN isn't seen in DevMan that is concerning. Maybe it was physically jiggled out of the card slot inside the PC? Sometimes WLAN cards install their our wireless mgmt SW that you have to use & they disable Windows controlling the wireless. Curious how realtek driver, 'manage wireless networks', or icon in bottom-right show wireless when no card is detected!?

Comment: A workaround if you can't fix it: USB WiFi adapters are available from US$8 and up.

Comment: Yes, I will buy an USB adapter if everything else fails.

Comment: There is no physical switch on my laptop. I do not know about the keyboard combination, but as far as I know the Wlan radio in BIOS should do the same thing.

Comment: I found the keyboard combination it Fn + F5 but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following way to see if there is wireless adapter showing:

1. Download and install **Lenovo Energy Management** according to the model of our computer on the official website of Lenovo.
2. When it is completed, restart the computer.
3. It will run automatically after restarting the computer after the normal installation is completed, but if it is not running automatically, we find this utility in the appropriate directory called **Start_Utility** and  double-click it, then it will run( There is no hint after it runs, but we can find the process of utility in the process, it displays like **utility.exe**).
4. Open the **Lenovo wireless device setting** module by pressing fn and f5.
5. Turn on the **wireless network card**.
6. View if there is wireless adapter showing.

Comment: I cannot open the Lenovo wireless device setting.